# dotnet test Coverlet wrong coverage

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, sonarqube, dockerfile

I'm builing a Jenkins pipeline using docker, sonarqube, coverlet. The results shown in Sonarqube are quite strange. See the image bellow, how can it be possible to cover lines inside the constructor but not cover the method signature?

[image]

There are a lot of extra strange behaviors, such as not covering objects initialization:

[image]

The code above is pretty basic, it should have 100% coverage because is linear, there are no conditions at all.

My project setting:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Dockerfile commands:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.405-focal AS build-env
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore MyProject.sln

RUN dotnet test MyProject.sln \
    /p:CollectCoverage=true \
    /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
    
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-sonarscanner
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

RUN export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"

RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"ProjectKey"  /n:"ProjectName" \
    /d:sonar.host.url="http://10.100.3.176:9000" \
    /d:sonar.verbose=true \
    /d:sonar.login="somehash" \
    /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="/tests/**/coverage.opencover.xml"

RUN dotnet build MyProject.sln

RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="somehash"
```

Comment: Did you check the coverage results itself? Maybe it's just an issue with displaying the result in sonarqube?

Comment: No, I didn't. However I found some recent related issues: https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1037... I might close this question I guess.

Comment: This is just a bug in coverlet.msbuild 3.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue today. Apparently, this happens if you have a method signature spanning over multiple lines. As someone pointed out in the comments section, updating the `coverlet.msbuild` nuget package to `>=3.0.3` resolves the issue.

Link to the GitHub issue - https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/1037